# Cannot attach a blur event to jQuery combobox

Tags: jquery-ui, combobox, blur

I am trying to add a 'blur' event to a jQuery combobox using the code below, but its always not firing. What would be the right way of attaching a 'blur' event to a jQuery combobox?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#dropdown_sel").combobox();
    $($('.ui-combobox-input')[0]).css('width', '500px');
    $("#toggle").click(function() {
        $("#dropdown_sel").toggle();
    });
    $("#dropdown_sel").blur(function() {
        alert('on blur of combo');
    });
});​
```

I even tried the code below but it fails to fire, where I use focusout event rather than blur event. I am using IE 8.x.

```
$("#dropdown_sel").focusout(function () { alert('on blur of combo'); });
```

You can test the code at this link, where I already have combobox code set up for focusout event: http://jsfiddle.net/vZwRk/79/

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`event-change`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#event-change):

```
$( "#dropdown_sel" ).bind( "autocompletechange", function(event, ui) {
    alert('on blur of combo');
});
```